# How to download PDF automatically using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

My scenario is that PDF file download automatically, then user fills it and when click on submit button in PDF it connect to java servlet and save it in DB.

1. User click on Button
2. JavaScript code run and PDF file download automatically
3. open file using JavaScript automatically
4. user fills & press submit
5. after submit servlet code run and save data in db

In my Application just the 2nd point is missing. Please provide code how to interact with extension using JavaScript to download file automatically.
I just want to download the file.

Comment: `document.location = 'url of pdf'`

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you just need an approach as @JaromandaX is showing above or be more specific on this.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use the [download attribute](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download).

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

Comment: Thats Great Its Working.Thanks a lot.Can we specify the path where the file is to be downloaded ?? chrome does not ask for path and take path programetically using javascript or HTML

Comment: @EhsaanIsrar we cannot. Browsers normally use the user settings for downloaded files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you tell me how to download automatically in xhtml ??i am working on a java based framework liferay portlet in which views are designed using xhtml and primefaces ??is there any way to download automatically in this

Comment: @EhsaanIsrar you can mark the answer as accepted though, can you not? I'm not sure what do you mean by 'automatically in xhtml'. The question was about javascript which should work just fine. You can add a script tag at the end of the body etc

Comment: @minj Thanks, This is the perfect solution, But I have one doubt, Can we set downloading time of file when file is downloading.

Comment: not working on latest chrome and Ubuntu 18.04 in june 2020, could you please tell what needs to be changed if any? as downloaded file is showing Failed, No file error and can't open a file, and instead of createElement('a'), how can I give element-id of any div?

Comment: I am trying to use this but on my console I see an error that says "Uncaught referenceError: url is not defined". I have tried placing my file link instead of url but that just causes it to download automatically without clicking the button. Any idea how to workaround this? @minj

Comment: this doesn't work. this opens the PDF on latest chrome nov 2021

Comment: It doesn't work on the latest Chrome Browsers

Comment: this doesn't work on Chrome

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to open the pdf link in a new window and let the browser handle the rest:

```
window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
```

or:

```
window.open(pdfUrl);
```

Comment: this opening the pdf file in new window, is there any way to directly download?

Comment: this works too although the new window opens and closes immediately which results in not great UX

Answer (score 5):

```
/* Helper function */
function download_file(fileURL, fileName) {
// for non-IE
if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = fileURL;
    save.target = '_blank';
    var filename = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    save.download = fileName || filename;
       if ( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(ipad|iphone|safari)/) && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
            document.location = save.href; 
// window event not working here
        }else{
            var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': false
            });
            save.dispatchEvent(evt);
            (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
        }   
}

// for IE < 11
else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
    var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    _window.document.close();
    _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
    _window.close();
}
}
```

> How to use?

```
download_file(fileURL, fileName); //call function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
       function validateEmail(email) {
            const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
           }
       
       if($('.submitclass').length){
            $('.submitclass').click(function(){
                $email_id = $('.custom-email-field').val();
                if (validateEmail($email_id)) {
                  var url= $(this).attr('pdf_url');
                  var link = document.createElement('a');
                  link.href = url;
                  link.download = url.split("/").pop();
                  link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
                }
            });
       }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-email-id form-group">
            <input placeholder="please enter email address" class="custom-email-field form-control" type="text" id="edit-email-id" name="email_id" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submitclass btn btn-danger" pdf_url="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or use **download attribute** to  tag in **HTML5**

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define the URL of the PDF file
var pdfUrl = "http://example.com/path/to/your/pdf.pdf";

// Function to trigger the download
function downloadPdf() {
  fetch(pdfUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      // Create a blob URL for the PDF data
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      // Create a link element to trigger the download
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "downloaded.pdf"; // Set the desired file name
      document.body.appendChild(a);

      // Trigger a click event on the link element to initiate the download
      a.click();

      // Clean up by revoking the blob URL and removing the link element
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Failed to download the PDF file: ", error);
    });
}

// Call the downloadPdf() function when needed, e.g., in response to a button click
document.getElementById("downloadButton").addEventListener("click", downloadPdf);
```

1. Replace http://example.com/path/to/your/pdf.pdf with the actual URL
   of the PDF file you want to download.
2. The fetch() function is used to make a GET request to the PDF file
   URL.
3. Once the response is received, the PDF content is converted to a
   blob, and a blob URL is created.
4. An anchor element () is dynamically created, and its href
   attribute is set to the blob URL. You can specify the desired file
   name using the download attribute.
5. The anchor element is appended to the document's body.
6. A click event is programmatically triggered on the anchor element to
   initiate the download.
7. Finally, the blob URL is revoked, and the anchor element is removed
   from the document to clean up.

You can call the downloadPdf() function in response to a button click or any other user action to initiate the download.

Answer (score -3):

1. for second point, get a full path to pdf file into some java variable. e.g. http://www.domain.com/files/filename.pdf

e.g. you're using php and $filepath contains pdf file path.

so you can write javascript like to to emulate download dialog box.

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = '<?php echo $filepath; ?>';
</script
```

Above code sends browser to pdf file by its url "http://www.domain.com/files/filename.pdf". So at last, browser will show download dialog box to where to save this file on your machine.

Comment: i tried this :`<script type="text/javascript">

 window.location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/EHSAAN/Desktop/chrome%20extension/practice/abc.pdf';

</script>` but it will open file not download it

Comment: window.location.href tells the url of file not download file

Comment: sorry, I meant to say below: should be fully qualified url to pdf file as shown below:

<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.location.href = 'http://www.domain.com/files/filename.pdf'
</script>

Comment: i give the complete path. i don't understand  what you say ? Please Elaborate

Comment: Well, full path means if you enter direct url to pdf into browser address bar, you can access it. right? so that full url has to be there into $filepath variable of PHP.

Comment: thanks a lot but i am not implement in php. i have to do in java, jsf, primefaces. can you help me ??

Comment: Sorry I don't know either of  java, jsf, primefaces, but it is just matter of creating "filepath" variable. Rest will be handled automatically.