# Multiple PDFdownloads

Tags: javascript

I have a local DB table in which many PDF links are saved around 15000. I want to download all that PDF   on one click but my problem is its opening PDF  not downloading. I  was trying this method.

```
items = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
items.forEach(function(item) {
    link = item.href;
    if (link.substr(link.length - 4) == ".pdf") {
        filename = link.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        item.download = filename;
        item.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do tag it properly, you have coded it up in JS it pops up under the php tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download PDF automatically using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js)

Answer (score 4):

You can not download all files using only 1 click. Instead of You can use ZIP Archive Class in PHP.

Make one zip file of all available pdf and download it.

```
$files = array('pdf1.pdf','pdf2.pdf');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
  }

  $zip->close();
```

And Headers Like

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: its download a zip file but display no archive found during extract. 

$files = array('https://assets.supply.com/ul_pdfs/309006_SpecSheet.pdf','https://assets.supply.com/ul_pdfs/574955_SpecSheet.pdf');

$zipname = 'file.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive;

$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
  }


  $zip->close();



header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
did i miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply,
this code works for me with zip archive

```
$files = array('pdflink','pdflink');
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($files as $file){
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
}   
$zip->close();
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
```

?>