# How can I download a pdf from a url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to download pdf's from one of our online resources.There is no built in function to batch download.The only way to do it is to navigate to each pdf file, click to open, then click download. 
There are several thousand files and this would take a very long time to do.
I got around this in the past using javascript. I gathered all the links to the pdfs, put them in a csv, and had the code loop through each link, download, and move onto the next link.

Unfortunately, I have lost that code and my efforts to recreate it have been unsuccessful.

I have tried everything in this article: [How to download PDF automatically using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js?answertab=active#tab-top)

I have tried the code from this article (which I'm pretty sure is what I did before): https://www.convertplug.com/plus/docs/download-pdf-file-forcefully-instead-opening-browser-using-js/

This is what I think should work...per the second article I referenced above

```
function download_file(fileURL, fileName) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = fileURL;
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
}
var fileURL = "link/to/pdf";
var fileName = "test.pdf";
download(fileURL,fileName);
```

The code above is just to test download one file from a hardcoded URL. If it worked as intended, when the page is loaded, it should download the pdf from the provided url. Instead, it doesn't do anything on load or refresh.
Any suggestions?

Comment: is it possible that the browser is not allowing your app to download multiple files?

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200312/how-to-allow-downloading-multiple-files-again-in-chrome

Comment: Try download_file not download

Answer (score 13):

Please check 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/18983688/6923146](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694012/6923146)

```
<a href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" download="sample.PDF">click me</a>
```

Another one 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905238/6923146

```
function download(url, filename) {
fetch(url).then(function(t) {
    return t.blob().then((b)=>{
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(b);
        a.setAttribute("download", filename);
        a.click();
    }
    );
});
}

download("https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.json","geoip.json")
download("data:text/html,Hello Developer!", "HelloDeveloper.txt");
```

I hope it helpfull

https://www.convertplug.com/plus/docs/download-pdf-file-forcefully-instead-opening-browser-using-js/

Comment: Thanks for the Info! It must have something to do with my browser. Both code snippets above just open the file at the URL, not download.

Comment: I just tried it again in Firefox and IE, but same results... so not a browser issue?

Comment: I am getting following error. `t.blob is not a function` If I remove the function parenthesis after the blob then the downloaded file is corrupted / empty.

Answer (score 7):

1. You must add link element to DOM

```js
function download_file(fileURL, fileName) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = fileURL;
  link.download = fileName;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}

var fileURL = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/img/jobs/bg-remote-header-sm.png";
var fileName = "test.pdf";
download_file(fileURL, fileName); // fix function name
```

2. Link must be in same origin

   > The download attribute on anchor was ignored because its href URL has a different security origin.

Comment: What does that mean? I was able to get Hardik's code to work but when I add my own url, it does nothing. The code you provided only brings me to the file, but does not download.

Comment: Ok, I just researched what "origin" means. How can I make this work if my script lives on the localhost?

Comment: Origin means you cannot download file from other url, only in current url the script is running

Comment: I have done this before, I just lost the code. Is it possible that my online resource added a security feature to prevent what I am doing? Like I said I made this work in the past.