# Angular how to get file from API

Tags: angular

I have API that returns PDF file, but in Angular when I call it it gives me this error

```
Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:1234/hebaback/public/api/download-report-20
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: '%PDF-1.3\n%�߬�\n3 0 obj\n<</Type /Page\n/Parent 1 0 R\n…1728F9DC34CF5EC66FE> ]\n>>\nstartxref\n2887591\n%%EOF'
```

the function is simple

```
downloadReport(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this._HttpClient.get(`http://localhost:1234/hebaback/public/api/download-report-${id}`)
}
```

I am sure that the error is from angular because I tried the API in postman and it works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `responseType` in the request `options` for Angular HttpClient to correctly parse the response. By default, Angular expects a JSON response, and hence, you're getting this error.

If server is returning `blob` then add it in the responseType. It also supports `text` and `arrayBuffer` for more flexibility, so configure the `responseType` accordingly.

```
return this._HttpClient.get(`http://localhost:1234/hebaback/public/api/download-report-${id}`, {responseType : 'blob'})
```

More details : https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Comment: thanks it worked but how can I download it? what to do with data after subscribe?

Comment: @OsamaAmr Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963990/how-can-i-download-a-pdf-from-a-url-using-javascript