# Download PDF in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, generate

Is there any documentation or anyone that can explain how I might go about creating a way to download a PDF of a page by clicking a button on another page?

To be specific, I have a page that shows a list of reports and I want the user to be able to press a download button that is located by each report and once pressed it downloads a PDF of the specific report you chose details page.

I have tried using IronPDF but other than that I cannot find any documentation that is helpful.

Comment: Your server-side application can't push the document to the user. Instead, you need to write client-side script to do the download. There is a ton of information available on how to do this. Here's the first one I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963990/how-can-i-download-a-pdf-from-a-url-using-javascript