# download file pdf- javascript

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, download

I try to download a pdf (inserted in the folder of my project) at the click of the user.
but when I download the file it says "operation failed"

```
function downloadFile() {
let link = document.createElement('a');
let file='data:application/pdf';
link.setAttribute('href',file);
link.download = 'l.pdf';
link.click();
}
```

Comment: Where’s the actual pdf data? If using a data href I’m thinking it will need the content of the pdf too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download PDF automatically using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js)