# How can I automatically download file when there is a link with some id

Tags: javascript, wordpress, download, advanced-custom-fields

I build a website on wordpress and I would like to website start download automatically when there is a link with PDF on subpage with some id for example "auto-download". File in the link is from ACF because my client wanted to add posts with specifications for his products and it should start downloading when the single blog post page will be opened.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer for this question here on stack overflow.

You might want to check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js)

If that doesn't solve your problem please let me know so I can provide a different explanation.