# HTML print page per table

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 5 table like this

[image]

and this is the result if print the page

[image]

but thats not what i wanted, i want to make one table for one page pdf, so there is 5 page each contains one table in pdf, is it possible? and how can i download the pdf directly after clicck the button, this is the button to go the print page
[image]

i also tried css page-break-after is not working, all the table still in one page print.
i hope you can understand my explanation, thanks

Comment: Read about Print CSS https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/.  For download button you can use this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694012/8298248