# Create an <a> tag that can download assets from its contentful environment?

Tags: javascript, html, contentful

I am trying to create an anchor tag that will link to a PDF asset in my Contentful space, so when the user clicks on the link the PDF file will be downloaded to his/her computer.

However, because the asset URL has not the same origin, the PDF will just open up within the browser itself.

Here is the current structure of the markup:

```
<a
  download="test.pdf"
  href="//assets.ctfassets.net/[contentfulID]/[contentfulID]/[contentfulID]]/test.pdf"
>
  <span>Download</span>
</a>
```

The problem, as I mentioned earlier, is that the asset URL does not have the same origin. Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download PDF automatically using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js)

Comment: @Naren Unfortunately I don't believe so as this doesn't address the issue of cross-origin downloads.

Comment: this seems to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down